# What's wrong with my SQL trigger creation statement?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to create some SQL triggers in SQLite3, under Python (3.5).

My test-case is as follows:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import sqlite3

sql_init = """
    CREATE TABLE ajxp_changes ( seq INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, node_id NUMERIC, type TEXT, source TEXT, target TEXT, deleted_md5 TEXT );
    CREATE TABLE ajxp_index ( node_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, node_path TEXT, bytesize NUMERIC, md5 TEXT, mtime NUMERIC, stat_result BLOB);

    CREATE TRIGGER LOG_DELETE AFTER DELETE ON ajxp_index BEGIN INSERT INTO ajxp_changes (node_id,source,target,type,deleted_md5) VALUES (old.node_id, old.node_path, "NULL", "delete", old.md5); END
    CREATE TRIGGER LOG_INSERT AFTER INSERT ON ajxp_index BEGIN INSERT INTO ajxp_changes (node_id,source,target,type) VALUES (new.node_id, "NULL", new.node_path, "create"); END
    """

conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
conn.executescript(sql_init)
```

This produces the following error:  `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "CREATE": syntax error`

The error disappears when the second `CREATE TRIGGER` statement is removed.

What gives?  I can't figure out what's wrong with my statement...

Comment: `END CREATE` isn't valid. Try testing your query into an actual SQL client

Comment: not a python guy but is your quoting valid?

Comment: Did you try to use `\"` instead `"`?

Comment: @cricket_007 Nice catch.  A semicolon fixes everything.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a semicolon after each `END` keyword fixes the issue.